# case label does not reduce to an integer constant

Tags: c, switch

Получаю такую ошибку на кейсах - `case label does not reduce to an integer constant`. Попробовал с `if` - все отлично, а вот с 'switch' не выходит. Обьясните почему происходит такая ошибка?

```
const int ACTION_EXIT_ID = 1;
const int ACTION_HIDE_ID = 2;
const int ACTION_SHOW_ID = 3;

//receive index value

switch(receiveIndex){
    case ACTION_EXIT_ID:
        printf("Exit action receive\n");
        break;
    case ACTION_HIDE_ID:
        printf("Hide action receive\n");
        break;
    case ACTION_SHOW_ID:
        printf("Show action recive\n");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Потому что это C, а не C++, вот он константы константами времени компиляции и не считает...

Comment: Вместо `const` используйте `#define`.

Comment: @zed, я знаю, просто интересно понять природу данной ошибки.

Comment: вам нужен `enum`.